# any way to entry the data in database using next.js 13.3.1-canary.4 and mongoose

Tags: next.js13

i want to create a register functionality using next.js 13.3.1-canary.4 and mongodb and show error "Internal server error"

register functionality using next.js 13.3.1-canary.4